How to make Nuxt open the component instead of .d.ts file when I CTRL + CLICK the html tag in VsCode?
Something annoying about Nuxt is that it's opening the TypeScript declaration file instead of the file itself when I CTRL/ALT + CLICK it, different from using Vue alone, Nuxt go to the declaration file inside .nuxt folder.
I'd like to make it to open the component directly, avoiding this extra step of opening the declaration file, then clicking the component path to go to the component file.
